# While loop in client thread (socket) only entered twice (android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, while-loop

I'm setting up a client thread for a server/client communication in Android. I can set up  the connection juste fine. But when I try looping with the code below the program only enters the while loop twice. (I also tried while(true) but nothing happens...).

I need the thread to wait for the client object to update the sendPicture/sendLinks etc.. to true for to send the example line pw.println("PICTURE").

On the server side (PC) it works juste fine (creating 1 ServerSocket for communication and others for FileTransfers.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Already tried: while(true)

```
public ClientSocketThread(String ip, int port, MainActivity.myClientSocketThreadHandler h, String message, Client c) {
        this.IP = ip;
        this.message = message;
        this.port = port;
        this.handler = h;
        this.client = c;
        this.clientName = c.getClientName();

    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(this.IP, port);
            Scanner is = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            pw = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            String line = "";
            pw.println(message);
            while (!line.equals("OVER")) {

                Log.i("ClientSocketThread", "------------------In true---------------------------------------------");

                if (is.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("Has next line");
                    line = is.nextLine();
                }else{
                    line = "";
                }

                System.out.println("______________________________Line: " + line);


                /**************************
                 * Connexion établie
                 */
                if (line.equals("PERMITTED")) {


                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("CONNECTION_NAME", this.connectionName);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    client.setConnectionAllowed(true);

                    /**************************
                     * Connexion refusé
                     */
                } else if (line.equals("REFUSED")) {

                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = 2;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("CONNECTION_NAME", this.connectionName);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);

                    disconnect();
                }


                /**
                 * On veut envoyer une image
                 */
                if (line.startsWith("DSS-PICTURE:")) {

                    System.out.println("Je suis dans le DDS-PICTURE");
                    Integer futurServerPort = Integer.valueOf(line.split(":")[1]);
                    PictureClientSocketThread pictureThread = new PictureClientSocketThread(this.IP, futurServerPort, client.getMyPictureHandler(), "None", client);
                    pictureThread.run();

                }


                if (client.getSendLink() == true) {
                    pw.println("LINK");
                    System.out.println("_______________________________SEND: LINK");
                    client.setSendLink(false);
                }

                if (client.getSendPicture() == true) {
                    pw.println("PICTURE");
                    System.out.println("_______________________________SEND: PICTURE");
                    client.setSendPicture(false);
                }

                if (client.getSendFile() == true) {
                    pw.println("FILE");
                    System.out.println("_______________________________SEND: FILE");
                    client.setSendFile(false);
                }

                if (client.getSendVideo() == true) {
                    pw.println("VIDEO");
                    System.out.println("_______________________________SEND: VIDEO");
                    client.setSendVideo(false);
                }


            }// End while


        } catch (
                Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The actual output stops here:

I/---MainActivity: ---------------bind finished

I/ClientSocketThread: ------------------In true---------------------------------------------

I/System.out: Has next line

______________________________Line: PERMITTED

I/ClientSocketThread: ------------------In true---------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()

> This method may block while waiting for input

Probably that's the case.